# rundll32.exe making outbound TCP connection

Tags: windows, networking, security, firewall, malware

I've been attempting to harden my network, and have taken some extra security precautions for the sake of learning, as well as.. to be secure. I've recently formatted and re-installed Windows 10, and have installed NetLimiter before enabling an internet connection to my machine.

On this fresh install it seems as if rundll32.exe (C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe) is making an outbound TCP connection to 52.86.141.238:80, which seems to be owned by amazon.. and when actually browsing to that website it takes me to Logitech's Support page. I do have a Logitech camera that is connected to my PC, so I'm wondering if that could be a potential cause? I'll try to reboot without the camera connected to see if it prevents the outbound traffic. It seems very strange to me that this is occurring, and I'd like to know what I could do to further investigate. Is there a way to see what DLL is actually triggering this outbound connection? Is there anyway this is some sort of malware and it's tunneling through amazon's hosting to direct me to Logitech's website?

What really throws me off is if I "ping support.logi.com" it shows the IP resolves to 104.16.53.111, not 52.86.141.238.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "I do have a Logitech camera that is connected to my PC, so I'm wondering if that could be a potential cause? " Most likely, any software installed can use rundll to make outside connections if designed to do so, most are used for product telemetry.

Comment: You could try to use "nslookup support.logi.com" command to see what's the IP address of this website

Comment: If you run Process Monitor, you can filter for just network events, and maybe even just filter for "TCP Connect" events.  Then you should be able to find the event and look at the stack.  Ideally with symbols setup you can see the module making the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above are helpful for additional commands, but I'm going to go ahead and answer this question in case someone comes along with the exact answer, or at least with something related.

First off, rundll32.exe is an executable program which enables sharing of DLL functions across process within the Windows. For rundll32.exe to be making an outbound TCP connection, one of the DLL functions loaded have to be making that connection. I was able to use Process Explorer by SysInternals to look at the rundll32.exe process and view the cli command run to start this process, which for me showed `"C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" C:\Windows\System32\LogiLDA.dll,LogiFetch`. I now knew that `LogiLDA.dll (Logitech Download Assistant)` was responsible for this, which backed my findings above and was good enough for me to allow the connection and move on. I could've gone one step further to decompile the DLL and view the inner function, but that's outside what I deemed necessary for this particular situation.

Hopefully that can help someone else!